# How to update multiple cell references of hyperlinks automatically?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, reference, cell

I have created several hyperlinks in a column, which links to another spreadsheet of the same workbook. Over there all the cell references are also in a column. Now i want to insert a row on the second page on the top of the sheet. As I do that the cell reference doesn't change and the previous cell figures drops down. How can i update multiple cell reference automatically as I insert row on top of the second sheet?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your specific situation but this is how I interpreted what you wrote: 
    [image: Sheet1 before Sheet2 change]
    [image: Sheet2 before adding row]
    [image: Sheet2 after adding row]
    [image: Sheet1 after Sheet2 change]

If this is off, let me know.

With that said, ensure that you aren't using absolute cell references in your first sheet.

Absolute cell references are denoted with a $ in font of either the column, row, or both.

Here is a reference from MS on Absolute, Relative, and Mixed cell references: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I guess I didn't put the question clearly. It's my fault. I have asked again now with images.